# knockoutjs - How to Create a List style app in with entry before adding list items

Tags: knockout.js

I've been working with a simple list, like the tutorial on [learn.knockoutjs.com](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections), "Working with Lists and Collections".  I want to have a list style app where a user picks a donation type and enters an amount, then adds the donation to a list.

The tutorial works by adding inputs when a button is clicked; I am struggling with how to have fixed inputs that add text values in a row instead.

The UI would look something like this, assuming two donations have been made, and the select started with three donation types, 1, 2, and 3:

```
Donation Type:  [select: Donation 3]
Amount: [text: $100.00]

[button: Add Donation]

Donations:

Type         Amount
-------------------------------
Donation 1   $10.00    [remove]
Donation 2   $20.00    [remove]

Total: $30.00
```

Questions:

1. I can't figure out how to remove donation types from the select list once they've been chosen.
2. If a donation is removed, the type associated with that reservation should reappear in the select list to be used with new donations.  I'm not sure how to do this either.
3. You'll notice that the jsfiddle uses a hardcoded donation that's pushed on to the list, when the button is added.  I don't know how to reference the select and input to use them when pushing donations onto the list.

Edit:

I've updated my question to give my actual use case and to try to clarify what my questions are; I initially used the list example from learn.knockoutjs.com because I thought it would be easier, but I think it's just confusing.

A JS Fiddle [for what I'm trying to do.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mgjdh/2/)

Comment: Ok, but where is your code what you've tried so far? How is your viewmodel and your html looks like?

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: He listed requirements...  Now go build his app for him...

Comment: I'm not asking to build my app for me. I'm struggling with modifying the tutorial on learn.knockoutjs.com to take user input before adding a list item, instead of after.  I've added a jsfiddle of what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in fact very close to making it work. The problem was that you did not define the `donationAmount` observable property in the main view model, which resulted in KnockoutJS failing when binding this unavailable property to the input tag.

Here is the part of the code that had to be changed so that it works now:

```
function DonationsViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            self.donationAmount = ko.observable();
            // ....
}
```

and here's some little change to your HTML:

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: availableDonations, optionsCaption: 'Please select...', value: selectedDonation, optionsText: 'label'"></select>
    <input data-bind="value: donationAmount"/>
    <button typ="button" data-bind="click: addDonation">Add Donation</button>
</div>
```

You can see the result on my [forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sdTfa/1/).

Comment: Thanks Jalayn, I've been struggling around with it since I posted the question, and have my most recent fiddle here -- http://jsfiddle.net/Mgjdh/4/.  I'm still trying to remove donation types from the select after they have been used, and re-add them if the donation is removed.  What is the advantage to using click as opposed to submit? I've seen both used in the knockoutjs documentation.

Comment: Thanks Nick, in fact there is an advantage using the "submit" binding if you also want to capture the "enter" key event in addition to the click on the submit button. In your case, I think now it's a good idea (and that's why I removed my comment) however I personally prefer using the click binding because it allows me to immediately see the action that is performed on the click (in HTML files with 2000+ lines, it really matters)

Comment: @NickSilberstein the submit is better but you'll need a `form` somewhere I guess to catch it. The click event will only work for the button while input will also trigger a submit event to the closest `form` tag. Also some browser feature like saving fields for autofill will only work with the submit event. That said, autofill with knockout sucks terribly because not every browsers trigger any event when autofilling inputs..

Comment: Your forked fiddle doesn't work quite right, but definitely helps solve the initial problem. Marking your answer as correct, thank you.